# Catching Google Maps API JavaScript RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using Google Maps API JavaScript library and I am looking for an advise how I can catch RefererNotAllowedMapError? I use application restriction on my keys and I need to make sure I handle this error properly but I do not understand how I can catch it.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error

What I observed is that the error occurs after the script is loaded. The script is loaded successfully and then a bit later the error appears.
I am loading the script dynamically and while loading no error occurs - the catch block is not entered, loaded successfully is printed.

```
this.loadScript(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=${key}&language=${language}`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('loaded successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error on loading');
      });

loadScript(url: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = url;
      script.text = '';
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      script.onload = resolve;
      script.onerror = reject;
      this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body, script);
    });
  }
```

Then, after this error occurs, when trying to use any of the provided in the library objects and their methods, for instance:

```
 const autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(request, (predictions, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          resolve([]);
        } else if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          resolve(predictions);
        } else {
          reject(new Error(status));
        }
      });
```

I do not get any error but the callback is never called so also here I am not able to do any handling.

Any help much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback parameter in the script url. The loadScript is probably resolving before the entire API has been loaded.

Alternatively, try using @googlemaps/js-api-loader.